help with understanding exactly what P(B) is when testing for independence of 2 events
I have some trouble with calculating or understanding exactly what $P(B)$ is when testing for independence of 2 events. Does P(B) use initial odds, or the total odds? I have two examples to demonstrate what I mean:
Example 1(I made this example)
We have 2 balls: 1 red, 1 blue. If a blue ball is picked then both the red and the blue ball is replaced with a blue, if a red ball is picked then its replaced with a red ball. Are the events are picking first red ball then a blue ball independent?
Here is pictures demonstrating this:

If we wanted to test for independence mathematically we would use the rule: P(A and B)=P(A)P(B)
If event A was picking red ball first, and event B was picking blue ball second.
Then $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$
$P(B) = P(blue \ blue)+P(red \ blue) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 = \frac{3}{4}$
$P(A \ and \ B) = P(red \ blue) = \frac{1}{4}$
thus we conconclude that $P(A)P(B) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{8} \neq \frac{1}{4} = P(A \ and \ B)$, thus the events are dependent
So for this example we had to go down the tree to find P(B) and found the total odds, but for the next example they don't seem to do this:
Example 2
Drawing a heart, do not replace the card, then draw another heart. Are the events indenpendent?
They would have $P(A) = \frac{1}{4}$, $P(B)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $P(A \ and \ B) = \frac{1}{4}*\frac{12}{51} = \frac{1}{17}$.
Thus as $\frac{1}{16}\neq \frac{1}{17}$, thus dependent.
From this it looks like $P(B)$ uses initial odds?
I know if you follow the Tree $P(B) = P(second \ pick \ H) = P(Heart \ Heart) + P(not \ Heart, Heart) = \frac{1}{4}*\frac{12}{51} + \frac{3}{4}*\frac{13}{51} = \frac{1}{4}$, so it is infact that $P(B) = \frac{1}{4}$, but they never ever show that they are actually doing it this way.
Questions

Is the first example the correct way to work it out?

I have only seen examples of very simple problems like example2, where it "seems" P(B) uses initial odds. They never explain this part. If I were to use initial odds for example1, then $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ which would give a false positive to independence of the 2 events. Are they doind the full check behinde the scenes? i.e: $P(B) = P(second \ pick \ H) = P(Heart \ Heart) + P(not \ Heart, Heart) = \frac{1}{4}*\frac{12}{51} + \frac{3}{4}*\frac{13}{51} = \frac{1}{4}$ or are there times where we only need to look at the initial odds?


I greatly appreciate any help you can offer

What do you mean by initial odds? Odds are not the same thing as probability. For example, the probability of getting a head on a fair coin flip is $\frac{1}{2}$ but the odds are $1:1$.

@JohnDouma I mean like "unconditional probability"


Firstly, never use use odds when you actually mean probability
Secondly, $P(A\;and\;B)$, generally now written as $P(A\cap B)$ uses the multiplication rule, but the multiplication rule is of two types, the special multiplication rule when the events are independent, $P(A).P(B)$ and the general multiplication rule when they are not: $P(A\cap B) = P(A).P(B|A)$ You would do well to study the various examples given in the link

To come now to the specific examples you have chosen

In the first example, since you have made it up, it confuses the issue. There is no unconditional probability for P(blue) or P(red) except for the first draw, and you are asking whether "the events  picking first red ball then a blue ball are independent"
In the second example, there are unconditional probabilities for drawing a heart at any place. If, (without looking), you are asked what is the probability that the fifth card, say, is a heart, the answer is still $\frac14$. So this thinking is used to simplify the computation that $P(B) = \frac14$

